# Upload file size is limited to 32kB and I get an error of "CGI.pm: Server closed socket during multipart read (client aborted?)."

Tags: javascript, html, perl, cgi

I'm attempting to upload a file and the server-side language used is Perl. The CGI module version is 3.15

for some weird reason I can upload any file below 32KB, but beyond that that filesize, I received the following error:

`CGI.pm: Server closed socket during multipart read (client aborted?).`

I tried setting the following parameters for CGI

`use CGI ':standard';`

`$CGI::POST_MAX=-1;`

`$CGI::DISABLE_UPLOADS=0; # Allow file upload`

but I still receive the error.

I hear that this problem is fixed in the newer version of CGI, but I cannot upgrade the CGI module, is there an alternative?

**Any ideas are welcome !!!**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The key to your problem seems to be here:

`CGI.pm: Server closed socket during multipart read (client aborted?).`

The error message seems to indicate that your server is closing the connection. If you are using Apache, nginx, whatever, check their config settings to increase maximum post request  body size.

Comment: Is there something else than : httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody that you might recommend me?

Answer (score 0):

I see you are setting `$CGI::POST_MAX = 1`, which is 1 byte.

Trying increasing it: `1024 * 100`.

From the [docs](http://search.cpan.org/~lds/CGI.pm-3.39/CGI.pm):

> > > `$CGI::POST_MAX`
> > >
> > > If set to a non-negative integer, this variable puts a ceiling on the size of POSTings, in bytes. If CGI.pm detects a POST that is greater than the ceiling, it will immediately exit with an error message. This value will affect both ordinary POSTs and multipart POSTs, meaning that it limits the maximum size of file uploads as well. You should set this to a reasonably high value, such as 1 megabyte.

Answer (score -2):

Read the whole documentation for CGI.pm, even if it's long. Somewhere there is a sub which sets a security maximum for file uploads. This is intended to make your server more DDOS-resistant. Just set a value you prefer. This would solve the 32kB part of the problem...

(I'm sorry that this wild guess didn't solve anything. Consider this answer deleted.)

Comment: "Read the whole documentation for CGI.pm, even if it's long."  Unbelievably simple advice that if followed would eliminate 40%+ of all StackOverflow questions.  While we're at it, let's link to it:  http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CGI

Comment: I've read the documentation and they suggested what I wrote above, by setting the variables for POST_MAX and DISABLE_UPLOAD

Comment: @DFIVE Next thing to check is if your server is configured to limit max post size as well.

Comment: @DavidO Is there such thing as a limit max post size on the server? Aren't these server-side language config, thus the CGI.pm?

Comment: -1: Reading documentation is always a good idea, but he already did that, and the error message indicates the error lies elsewhere (the server.)

Comment: @DondiMichaelStroma: I relialize that by now, as more information has become available about the problem since I wrote that post.